# hiding the editor window form a perspective in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

Once and for all, ban the editor (source code editor) windows from mingling my 'DDMS' perspective. How to do that ?

EDIT: 
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 1.2.2.20100216-1730
Build id: 20100218-1602

with the only available updates being for Mylin and Android something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can minimize the editor area using a button in the top-right corner of the editor area. That let's you see that it's minimized in the window frame (along the right side) and easily Restore it.

Alternatively, you can set up a keyboard shortcut to really toggle the editor area visibility. Open the Preferences and navigate to **General > Keys** (or press `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + L` *twice* to jump right to the Keys preferences). Search the commands for `area` and then assign a keyboard shortcut to the **Toggle Editor Area Visibility** command. *Note: for older versions of Eclipse (3.5 and older), the command is named **Hide Editors**.*

There is no way to permanently remove the Editor Area from a Perspective; that's fundamental to how Eclipse is designed.

Comment: Thanks. I could not find "Toggle Editor Area Visibility" or anything related among the General>Keys or among the keyboard assist listings. See my edited question for some extra info

Comment: That's a pretty old version of Eclipse (almost 3 major releases old). I updated my answer to help with your version, but I still recommend either using the Minimize button or, better yet, get the latest version of Eclipse. I think the latest Android plugins require (or at least recommend) Eclipse Helios or Indigo (3.6/3.7).

Comment: found it. it gets hidden, but not banned unfortunately. Not long ago, clicking on various links (from exceptions in Console for instance) inside the DDMS perspective would have opened the appropriate editor in the Java perspective. Now it just keeps openning the editor in DDMS perspective. Which is nonsense :|

Comment: It's not nonsense, it's keeping with the design of Eclipse. There is always an Editor Area and the IDE doesn't generally yank your Perspective out from under you unless you explicitly ask to change. Those are intentional decisions and fundamental to how Eclipse is designed.
ADT used to automatically switch to the Java Perspective when clicking a stack trace in the LogCat view, but that was fixed with a  Preference setting a while ago (see https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/20668/).

Comment: I don't think the standard Console view has ever switched the Perspective when clicking a link; if it did it was likely a bug or oversight that has since been fixed.