# Banning an editor from a multi-editor perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I've been experimenting with multiple editors in Eclipse. I've created a perspective Java (4K), based on default Java perspective, but with multiple editors for when I plug the laptop into my 4K TV. That way a bigger screen enables me to edit multiple files at a time.

However, one of the editors in 4K is the one from the default Java perspective, which I don't want. Just like editors in the 4K perspective are banned from the default, I want the one editor from the default perspective banned in 4K. Is that possible?

I've seen how to hide an editor view in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9514056/4226093), saying that editor views can't be banned. But it seems to me they can:

When I open the 4K perspective I have (at the moment) 5 editors with 5 different files open, let's call them A, B, C, D and E. I switch to the default perspective and only the editor with A is there. If I want to open file C, for example, it will add a tab to the editor with A rather than show the existing editor with C already open, so clearly **that editor is banned**.

Unfortunately, in the 4K perspective, I haven't been able to ban the editor that's in the default perspective. I have managed to hide it, so there are 4 editors with B, C, D and E. Let's say that last time I was using default (as I was using the small screen) i opened a new file F. Of course, it opened as a new tab in the editor already having A and C. But after switching to 4K, if I want to open file A or F, whatever I do, the editor view with A, C and F will re-emerge. I don't want that editor to re-emerge.

How do I do it? Are perspectives the right approach?

**So in short:**

I want to be able to switch between a small and large mode (perspective?).

In the small mode I want one editor with multiple tabs when I open new files (regardless of whether they'd been opened in the large mode, which works fine).

In the large mode I want to be able to open files in existing or new editor views regardless of whether they'd been opened in the small mode (not working at the moment).

How do I do it?

**UPDATE**

[image: 1 editor view, 3 tabs]

This, as far as I understand, is a single editor view with 3 tabs. But, as greg-449 pointed out in a comment, the 3 tabs are apparently **3 editors**.

[image: 2 editor views, 1st is empty, 2nd has 2 tabs]

Now the editor area is populated, as I understood, by 2 editor views, the left one is empty and the right one has 2 tabs. Does that mean the right *thing* contains two editors? And what is the left *thing*?

Anyway, this is what I see at the moment if I switch to the "Java (HD)" perspective, while I see one big empty *thing* (the left one) if I switch to the "Java (default)" perspective. The right *thing* (whatever it is) is **banned** in the default perspective, as when in default, if I open Test.java, it will open it in the big empty *thing*, and not bring the one on the right from the HD perspective. Then, when switching to the HD perspective, the left *thing* will be in the same state as I'd left the big *thing* in the default perspective, i.e. having files open in tabs that I'd opened using the default perspective.

Now, as the right *thing* is banned in the default perspective, why can't I ban the left *thing* from the HD perspective? Am I looking at it wrong way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'one editor with multiple tabs', most editors don't support multiple tabs. Despite what you say editors can't be 'banned' from a perspective.

Comment: Do you mean that on a larger screen, the editors should be displayed side by side (editor area split vertically), whereas on a smaller screen only one editor should be displayed (one editor covers the whole editor area)?

Comment: @howlger Yes, but the editor area is also split horizontally. The 4K screen has resolution 3840x2160.

Comment: @greg-449 Java (default) perspective has a single editor view and when you open more than 1 file it has tabs so you can switch which one of the files you can see and edit. The tabs also indicate with asterisks which files have unsaved changes.

Comment: Those tabs are separate editors, not one editor with multiple tabs.

Comment: @greg-449 Separate editors? But although there are multiple editors, is there one **editor view**? Also see the update, obviously the first picture is what we were just discussing...

Comment: The whole area containing editors is the "Editor Area", each section with the tabs is a "Part Stack". I can't say I have looked at a split editor area likes this so I don't know exactly how they are handled.

Comment: @greg-449 I might need to re-phrase the question completely. I thought that a view with tabs to edit files was an "editor" or "editor view". I think I've worked out what to do though. The additional "editor views" / "part stacks" / "*things*" / whatever can easily be in only one perspective while the original one is in all of them (but can be hidden). So instead of Java (default) I could use another custom perspective. I'll try this now...

Comment: It did sort-of solve it. When I open a new file, it un-hides the original "editor view" / "part stack" and opens it inside it, so I have to move it to an additional one and re-hide the original one, keeping it empty. I've got 3 perspectives in use: "Java (small)" (see one file at a time), "Java (HD)" (see 2 files side-to-side, might split vertically later) and "Java (4K)" (see 3x2 files at a time, enough room to divide into 4 or 5 horizontally). So depending on which screen I use, I just switch perspective to have the same files (editors) laid out the most convenient way.

Comment: Actually, it's same files but not same editors. I might introduce an in-between perspective for the 4K TV (using a resolution less than 4K but more than HD) as it's only 43 inch so the details are a bit small (unless I look at the telly closely). Anyway, thanks everyone trying to help, I guess this will do for now.